# Google Analytics page views and page hits

Tags: google-analytics

I have Google Analytics tag in my site and it seems that GA (4-10 views) is much lower in reporting page views as opposed to my web app which reports around 350 views.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Is Google Analytics page views reliable source?

Comment: Does your web app take into account views from spiders and bots? They can hammer a site with impressions if you aren't blocking or removing them.

Comment: Most likely @drummin is correct. Can you segment your apps' view data by User-Agent? If so, just take a look at how many of the hits are from GoogleBot and BingBot, and you'll have a rough estimate of how many "views" can be attributed to bots.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics works by executing JavaScript after the page load to register a page view. Most bots and web spiders simply load HTML part and do not execute JavaScript, therefore page view is not reported to GA.